# Acumulative sum in R

Tags: r, cumsum

I have data containing columns x and lx, I want to get cumulative sum on lx basis. My data is like:

| x | l(x) |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 100.000 |
| 21 | 99.644 |
| 22 | 99.286 |
| 23 | 98.925 |
| 24 | 98.561 |
| 25 | 98.195 |
| 26 | 97.829 |

and I want to get output like :

| x | l(x) |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 692.440 |
| 21 | 592.440 |
| 22 | 492.796 |
| 23 | 393.510 |
| 24 | 294.585 |
| 25 | 196.024 |
| 26 | 97.829 |

ie. accumulative sum

So it there a possible way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `rev`erse the column, get the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) and `rev`erse the output

```
df$`l(x)` <- with(df, rev(cumsum(rev(`l(x)`))))
```

-output

```
#  x    l(x)
#1 20 692.440
#2 21 592.440
#3 22 492.796
#4 23 393.510
#5 24 294.585
#6 25 196.024
#7 26  97.829
```

---

Or another option is `revcumsum`

```
library(spatstat.utils)
df$`l(x)` <- revcumsum(df$`l(x)`)
```

---

Or using `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(`l(x)` = accumulate(`l(x)`, `+`, .dir = 'backward'))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = 20:26, `l(x)` = c(100, 99.644, 99.286, 98.925, 
98.561, 98.195, 97.829)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
df[, 2] <- Reduce("+", df[, 2], accumulate = TRUE, right = TRUE)

   x    l(x)
1 20 692.440
2 21 592.440
3 22 492.796
4 23 393.510
5 24 294.585
6 25 196.024
7 26  97.829
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cumsum` like below

```
transform(
  df,
  `l(x)` = sum(`l(x)`) - cumsum(c(0, head(`l(x)`, -1)))
)
```

which gives

```
   x    l.x.
1 20 692.440
2 21 592.440
3 22 492.796
4 23 393.510
5 24 294.585
6 25 196.024
7 26  97.829
```